# Simple reverse proxy with Traefik

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, apache2

I'm currently using Apache as proxy for my LXD containers, using this kind of settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.142/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.142/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to switch to [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/). I have tried this configuration:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[backends]
  [backends.backend1]
    [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
       url = "http://10.0.0.142"

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
      backend = "backend1"
      passHostHeader = true
      [frontends.frontend1.routes.example]
          rule = "Host:example.com"
```

- Are these two equivalent?
- Can the traefik configuration be simplified? (remove unnecessary rules)

(Note: I'm not planning on using docker, and I would prefer not to.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are missing the backend type definition (file, Docker, Swarm...).

In your case just add (or uncomment) `[file]` in your conf file, like that:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[file]

[backends]
  [backends.backend1]
    [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
       url = "http://10.0.0.142"

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
      backend = "backend1"
      passHostHeader = true
      [frontends.frontend1.routes.example]
          rule = "Host:example.com"
```

Comment: So [file] is required? I didn't find anything about that. Why its so?

Comment: yes it is if you simply want to manually create rules statically in a configuration file. You can refer to the doc: [https://docs.traefik.io/toml/#file-backend](https://docs.traefik.io/toml/#file-backend)

Comment: ok. got it. Thanks! (do you mind to upvote my question? not sure why it was downvoted)

Comment: Good question- was stuck there for an hour...

Comment: Updated Doc link: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/file/